# Is a for loop faster than map in some cases?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question is really what the title says.

The reason for the question:
The `map` func is slower than the `for` loop in the code below.
Is it because of some problem in my code, or is there something else??

Code:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
def translate(x):
    x[1]+=1
    x[2]+=1
    x[3]+=1

atoms = [[1,1,1,1]]*1000
'''
smt1 = '''for i in atoms: translate(i)'''
smt2 = '''map(translate, atoms)'''

time_for = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=smt1)
time_map = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=smt2)

print time_for.timeit(10000)
print time_map.timeit(10000)
```

Output(Windows 7(64-bit) I-3 2nd gen):

```
>>> 
3.4691164256
3.5064888507
```

Output(Windows 7(32-bit) core2duo):

```
>>>
5.58571625252
6.25803459664
```

---

I guess I should mention that I am using Python 2.7.3, so although `map` in Python 3 is a generator, it is not so in Python 2, so this "problem" can't be replicated on Python 3.

---

**Update:**

To address those who said that atoms should be immutable, here's a different version of setup (it's slower, but still shows the difference):

```
setup = '''
def translate(x):
    return tuple(i+1 for i in x)

atoms = [(1,1,1,1)]*1000
'''
```

Output(Windows 7(32-bit) core2duo):

```
>>> 
31.0213507144
29.7194933508
```

Comment: `[[1,1,1,1]]*1000` actually creates 1000 copies of same object.

Comment: Proving a statement with an existential qualifier only requires one example, which you've provided, so... yes.

Comment: Please be aware that your two operations aren't doing the same thing.  (Can you spot why they're different?)

Comment: The difference you show is too small. Though I can't imagine why you think map would be faster in this case, the benchmark does not strongly state that one approach is better or the other. What you observe could easily be noise.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Added the time for the other system that I have.

Comment: I agree with Ivaylo Strandjev - in fact, running the test several times here gives variable results as to which is faster. On Python 2.7, the weakness of `map()` is that it builds a result list, and the weakness of `for` is that the iteration is in Python bytecode rather than C.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev -- I can reproduce this ordering reliably on my machine.  I don't think it's noise *for my machine*.  I'm guessing it's a matter of the particular OS and how the underlying C library functions perform for that platform/compiler.

Comment: I think the best answer to this question is just “Yes, a for-loop is faster than a map *in some cases*.” – It just depends a lot on what you are doing…

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I forgot to thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `map` with `filter` to avoid the overhead of building the result list. Seems to be about 10% faster than all the other options mentioned so far.

Answer (score 5):

That is because `map` creates a new structure whereas `for` only modifies the current one.

Comment: Even though this statement is correct, it apparently doesn't account for the differences.  (see my answer).  Even building a list, `map` still ends up slower.

Comment: I should preface this... even building a list, `map` still ends up slower **on my machine**.  With timings this close, you can get significant variation from computer to computer and OS, etc.

Answer (score 4):

A few observations.

- Usually it's a bad idea to do `[[1,1,1,1]]*n`.  This creates `n` references to *the same list*.  It's fine to do `[None]*n` though as `None` is immutable.
- you're building a list with map but not with the loop.  That introduces some overhead
- there's another option (list comp)

---

```
import timeit

setup = '''
def translate(x):
    x[1]+=1
    x[2]+=1
    x[3]+=1

atoms = [[1,1,1,1] for _ in range(1000) ]
'''
smt1 = '''lst = []
for i in atoms: lst.append(translate(i))'''
smt2 = '''map(translate, atoms)'''
smt3 = '''[translate(i) for i in atoms]'''

time_for = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=smt1)
time_map = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=smt2)
time_lc  = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=smt3)

print time_for.timeit(10000)
print time_map.timeit(10000)
print time_lc.timeit(10000)
```

With that said. **`map` is still slower for me**.

```
7.49916100502
7.83171486855
6.13082003593
```

and list comprehension wins hands down.

As a point of style however, I would definitely use the `for` loop here.  Since you're not returning anything from `translate`, it is the cleanest alternative.  Using `map` and `list-comprehensions` for "side effects" is generally not preferred practice.

Comment: Are you testing on 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Same test, `4.527` vs. `3.604` vs. `3.900` on my computer (Py 2.7-x64 on Win8-x64).

Comment: @Aya 2.7.3 (notice the print statement) and on python3, `map` would return almost instantly since it wouldn't actually *do* anything.

Comment: `[[None]]*n` is not advisable, since it references the same list `[None]` n-times! What you probably mean is `[None]*n`, which is fine.

Comment: @poke -- It's not surprising to me that you get different results on windows with a different python version.  what do you get if you remove the list appending from the for loop though?  that might bring it on par with the others and that is the one OP *should* be using since he/she isn't actually returning anything from `translate`.

Comment: @DavidZwicker -- that's precisely what I meant.  I suppose that's what I get for answering questions on a bus after a long night on a plane...

Comment: @mgilson D'oh, and d'oh. Both very good points. I notice when I used `dis` on the functions that `map()` seems to do its iteration in C, rather than Python bytecode. I don't suppose there's an easy way to do that without the overhead of building a result list?

Comment: @mgilson -- I know it was a minor point, but python beginners are often confused by this. That's why I wanted to make it clear :)

Comment: There's an UPDATE!!! Also, you are right, an immutable object is mor appropriate, so have tuple.

Comment: @Aya -- Nope, no easy way, although it's probably not too bad to create an extension with `Cython`.  Generally that's not a concern though.  Only optimize this stuff out if you can reliably prove that it makes a significant difference in the total run-time of the program.  Even then, with a function this simple, you'd probably do best if you in-lined it in the for loop rather than using a function+map or even a function + list comp.

Comment: @mgilson I get `3.529` (for-loop without creating something) vs. `3.587` (list comprehension) then.

Comment: @mgilson Actually, I managed to do it using `reduce()`, and a two-param callback which ignores one of the params, and it seems to run about 10% faster on average. But, yeah, the most readable solution is usually the best one. Edit: Hmm. I s'pose `filter()` with a function which always returns `False` might be better.

Comment: @Aya -- Fair enough.  It *can* be done, but I still contend that those aren't "easy" ;-) and they definitely aren't clean solutions.

Comment: @mgilson Well, by "easy" I really meant "without writing any C code". ;-) But it turns out you can just `s/map/filter/` in the original code, and get a reasonable speed improvement, but, sure, it's kinda 'messy'.

Answer (score 2):

Your translate function is wrong as it actually returns `None`. And atoms = `[[1,1,1,1]]*1000` is nothing but a copy of same object 1000 times.

Here's my timing results:

```
In [49]: def translate(x):
    x[:3]=[y+1 for y in x[:3]]
    return x
   ....: 
In [54]: lis = [[1,1,1,1] for _ in xrange(10**5)]
```

using `map()`:

```
In [55]: %timeit map(translate,lis)
1 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop
```

For-loop:

```
#this is fast as no list is created in this, i.e you're not storing the 
#returned value anywhere. So technically it's not equivalent to a LC or `map`.

In [56]: %timeit for i in lis: translate(i)  
1 loops, best of 3: 146 ms per loop
```

List comprehension:

```
In [57]: %timeit [translate(i) for i in lis]
1 loops, best of 3: 153 ms per loop
```

From the [docs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops):

> Python supports a couple of looping constructs. The for statement is
>   most commonly used. It loops over the elements of a sequence,
>   assigning each to the loop variable. If the body of your loop is
>   simple, the interpreter overhead of the for loop itself can be a
>   substantial amount of the overhead. This is where the `map` function
>   is handy. You can think of map as a for moved into C code. The only
>   restriction is that the "loop body" of map must be a function call.
>   **Besides the syntactic benefit of list comprehensions, they are often as fast or faster than equivalent use of map.**

So in most cases `map` outperforms a list comprehension only when used with a `built-in` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate your results in Python 3.3 (both `map` and `range` now return a *lazy iterator* rather than a list):

```
In [7]: %timeit list(map(lambda x: x + 1, range(1000)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 218 us per loop

In [8]: %timeit [x + 1 for x in range(1000)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.5 us per loop
```

Comment: Your benchmark is very different from OP's, so the results are not as easily comparable.

Comment: @delnan - sure, they're not doing the same thing. My version should be a more direct comparison of `map` and `for` than OP.

Comment: Your version doesn't benchmark a `for` loop though, it benchmarks list comprehension.

Comment: @delnan List comprehension compiles to the same bytecode as `for`.

Comment: @poorsod: It also produces a new list in memory, which a `for` loop does not.

Comment: @chepner Depends what you're doing in the `for` loop, surely?

Comment: @poorsod: The `for` loop itself does not a produce a list; the code in the body is another story. A list comprehension *always* produces a new list. It is not simply syntactic sugar for applying a function to each item of an iterable.

Comment: @chepner If you want to objectively compare a method which generates a list, with something else which *can* generate a list, then you will have to make it do that in order to get comparable results.

Comment: @chepner Sure, if you don't compare equivalent code you won't get the same result...

Comment: @poorsod See the back-quote at the end of Ashwini's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your two operation do different things.

`smt1` iterates through your list, translates each item and throws away the result. `smt2` actually translates all elements and returns a list which contains all the changed objects.

So the map is actually more complicated than the first statement, simply because it stores all the translated items.

You can change the first statement to a list comprehension to make it return the same result:

```
smt1 = '''[translate(i) for i in atoms]'''
```

When I do that, I get the following results:

```
3.8775811587063767    list comprehension
3.4751189085098315    map
```

Also note that in Python 3, `map` became a generator. This means that it *lazily* performs that translation as you request more items from it. So that is actually another reason to prefer map here.

Comment: If you don't need a list of `None` values (which is what either `map` or a list comprehension produces when given `translate`), you shouldn't use either in place of a `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner I don’t think we really need to discuss the `translate` function here; the tests are fundamentally different.

Comment: My point is that if you don't need the new list, neither `map` nor a list comprehension should be used simply as a syntactic alternative to a `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner The original intention is not really clear in the question, so that’s all just wild guessing. It’s not clear if it was intended that the function returns nothing, the `atoms` list contains 1000 times the same reference, nor that the for-statement didn’t produce a list. From the help for `map` it should be clear that a list is generated, so I actually doubt that it was just a way to apply stuff to throw-away objects.

Comment: @chepner And with the now updated question, I guess this is cleared up, right?